# How to add blank into char column sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with a `column [char](8) NOT NULL DEFAULT (' ')`.
I've changed this column to `char(21)`. For all existing rows I need to have blank characters from 9 to 21 position. Instead the `len()` is 8 and the blank characters are collapsed.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The char columns do have trailing spaces, but LEN() *ignores* trailing spaces, hence your misunderstanding.

See sample below:

```
create table char8(char8 char(8) not null constraint df_char8 default(' '), i int);
insert char8 (i) select 1
insert char8 (char8) select 't'

select char8, len(char8), len(char8+'.')-1 from char8

char8                
-------- ----------- -----------
         0           8
t        1           8

alter table char8 drop constraint df_char8
alter table char8 alter column char8 char(21)

select char8, len(char8), len(char8+'.')-1 from char8

char8                
-------- ----------- -----------
         0           21
t        1           21
```

Using the column+'.' makes the trailing spaces significant, so you get 9 and 22 respectively using LEN.  Take one off and that is what the column contained.

You may also notice that even **on display**, CHAR(21) strips off trailing spaces, which shows special treatment of trailing spaces by SQL Server for char columns in at least 2 scenarios (LEN, result display in SSMS).

Answer (score 0):

You could bypass the LEN() function trimming combining it with a REPLACE if you just need to have the exact length, spaces included:

```
LEN(REPLACE(column, ' ','*'))
```